# Using ldapsearch with a server over ssl but no password

Tags: macos, ldap

Our organization requires SSL for access to our ldap server.  When I set up our LDAP server in Mac OS X's Contacts application, I am able to search just fine for people in our organization.  However, using the command line app ldapsearch doesn't seem to work.

The problem is that our organization, while using SSL, does not require a username or a password.  I can't seem to get ldapsearch to not require a password.

Here's the command I'm using:

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.example.com -b "" -s base "objectclass=*" 
SASL/DIGEST-MD5 authentication started
Please enter your password:
```

Here is the contents of my /etc/openldap/ldap.conf

```
HOST ldap.example.com
PORT 636
TLS_REQCERT never
```

Here are the settings that work just fine in Mac OS X's Contacts application, and don't require a username or password:

[image: ldap example]

What's the correct ldapsearch concoction to use for this server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the -x option. Try something like:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap.example.com -b "ou=people,dc=examplelabs,dc=com" -s sub "objectclass=inetorgperson"
```